# ReorderableListview.builder can give us callbacks over dragging starts and stop callbacks on dragging stops?

Tags: flutter, dart, reorderable-list

Does reorderablelistview.builder gives us the callbacks when we start dragging and it continuously gives us callback while we drag widget up and down. Because i want to have a callbacks when we start dragging behaviour of a widget in reorderablelistview.builder.